# New LinkedIn-SDK doesn't work on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, linkedin-api

I implemented new linkedIn-sdk in my app. It's work correct on two iPhone devices. But when i use iPad and try create linkedIn session with method from LISDKSessionManager class:

```
+ (void)createSessionWithAuth:(NSArray *)permissions state:(NSString *)state showGoToAppStoreDialog:(BOOL)showDialog successBlock:(AuthSuccessBlock)successBlock errorBlock:(AuthErrorBlock)erroBlock;
```

linkedIn-sdk opens linkedIn app and show sign in or profile screen, then... nothing happens! I didn't get any response from linkedIn app :(. Success/Error block didn't call too.

On device i have only this logs:

```
LinkedIn[621] <Error>: assertion failed: 12H143: libxpc.dylib + 51923 [7FF71721-5624-3DDE-9615-146A4D8B7197]: 0x7d
Unknown[621] <Error>:
backboardd[56] <Warning>: CoreAnimation: updates deferred for too long
backboardd[56] <Warning>: CoreAnimation: timed out fence 3073b
SpringBoard[42] <Warning>: CoreAnimation: failed to receive fence reply: 10004003
backboardd[56] <Warning>: CoreAnimation: failed to send fence reply: 10000003
LinkedIn[651] <Warning>: Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <LiCoLoginViewController: 0x14659dd0>.
```

Please, anybody can help me?

Comment: Did you find out? I'm also seeing this